# How to store a number more than 9 digits in c?

Tags: c, typedef

When I surfed through the internet, I went out with the following type definition coding. I think it probably works. But, I can't understand the coding. Can you explain me the following coding:

```
    #define RADIX (10)
    #define DIGIT_BIT (4) /* A better way than hardcoding 4? */
    #define DIGIT_PER_BYTE (CHAR_BIT/DIGIT_BIT)
    #define DIGIT_BIT_MASK (~(UINT_MAX << DIGIT_BIT))
    typedef struct ThirteenDigitNum 
      {
        char unsigned digits[13/DIGIT_PER_BYTE + !!(13%DIGIT_PER_BYTE)];
      } ThirteenDigitNum;
    typdef struct DigitAccessInfo 
      {
        unsigned byte_index;
        unsigned shift_by;
        unsigned mask;
      };
```

Is there any build-in datatype to meet my needs?

Comment: don't think it terms of digits. think in terms of bits. 8/16/32/64. if you want to exceed thel imit of those bit lengths, then you'll have to use other means, e.g. strings.

Comment: Most architectures/compilers support a 64-bit data type, which would let you store a number as big as 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: Use double. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like long long int gives you over 18 digits, using the C++ standard (and, per comment below, C as well).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: Note that it's not limited to C++. In fact C99 Standard introduced `long long` type (it might be available as compiler's extension in older one).

Comment: yes!!! I got success in using long long... But, What is the main objective of the above code???

Comment: @kalyan:  that code would be useful if you wanted to allow some ginormous number of digits.  But, no, it's clearly not needed if you only want 13 digits.